# Dismiss SVProgressHUD if exiting View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, svprogresshud

I have a view controller that on launch shows an SVProgressHUD as data is fetched from the server. How would I dismiss the SVProgressHUD if moving back to the previous view controller before the fetch is completed?

I have tried this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
     super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
            print("before dismiss")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            print("after dismiss")
        }
}
```

I get the error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Here is some code from the view controller that is being navigated back to:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchRestaurants.delegate = self
        loadRestaurants()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //navigation bar title edit
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkboard SE", size: 17)!]

        //fetch list of restaurant names from database
        //set table cells to values inside array
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
            let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
            let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
            dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
                print("This is run on the background queue")
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set super.viewWillDisappear(animated) at the end.

Comment: Still return the same error

Comment: is it a push / pop segue inside a navigationcontroller? or do you present the viewcontroller modally?

Comment: It is the back button automatically initialised from navigation controller. It seems as if the error comes from the view controller that is navigated back to after navigating back now. However, there were no issues of this kind until after I added the above function.

Comment: can you show some code from the previous viewcontroller then?

Comment: I have edited my question. However, as I said, this view controller loads without issue when segueing to it from it's parent view controller. This error has only come up after `override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
     super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
            print("before dismiss")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            print("after dismiss")
        }
}`

Comment: add an exception breakpoint and see where exactly the app crashes: http://imgur.com/h9JD0DO

Comment: This is where the error is occurring: `self!.restaurantsArray.append(fetchedRestaurant.objectForKey("Name") as! String)` This line is part of another parse query in the parent view controller.